# Can the intersection of infinitely many open sets be neither open nor closed?

Tags: general-topology

We all know the example of infintely-many open sets intersecting in a singleton (closed), but is there an example where the intersection is neither open nor closed?

Comment: Let $U_n=\left(-\frac1n,1\right)$; then $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}U_n=[0,1)$.

Comment: Consider the irrational numbers.

Comment: *(to continue Asaf Karagila's hint)* Consider intersections of complements of singleton sets.